# Dependency injection using microsoft unity

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dependency-injection

I am trying to implement dependency injection based upon [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2014/01/23/introduction-to-dependency-injection-with-unity.aspx).
In this article there are two types of games one

a) Tic Tac Toe

b) TrivialPursuit

The type registration is done by the following code

```
// Declare a Unity Container
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
// Register IGame so when dependecy is detected
// it provides a TrivialPursuit instance
unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, TrivialPursuit>();
// Instance a Table class object through Unity
var table = unityContainer.Resolve<Table>();
Console.WriteLine(table.GameStatus());
Console.ReadLine();
```

If I had multiple games and wanted some logic in the business layer to decide which game to select

a) Tic tac toe

b) Mario

c) TrivialPursuit

Would I have to register the three game separately. What is the best approach if i need to ensure it works for all games and when the code can select the game depending upon the game passed.

Is there any Vb.net example.

```
// Declare a Unity Container
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
string game ;
if(game="tictactoe")
{
    // it provides a TictacToe instance
    unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, TictacToe>();
    // Instance a Table class object through Unity
    var table = unityContainer.Resolve<Table>();
    Console.WriteLine(table.GameStatus());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
elseif(game="TrivialPursuit")
{  
    // Register IGame so when dependecy is detected
    // it provides a TrivialPursuit instance
    unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, TrivialPursuit>();
    // Instance a Table class object through Unity
    var table = unityContainer.Resolve<Table>();
    Console.WriteLine(table.GameStatus());
     Console.ReadLine();
}
elseif(game="Mario")
{  
    // Register IGame so when dependecy is detected
    // it provides a Mario instance
    unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, Mario>();
    // Instance a Table class object through Unity
    var table = unityContainer.Resolve<Table>();
    Console.WriteLine(table.GameStatus());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: BTW, I don't see ANY vb.net here

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to register all games and let the business logic decide what game should be created by choice of user.

It may not be the best approach because there might be better one aside from this but let me introduce my solution.

Solution Context :

- I registered all games with unique name like tictactoe, trivaiapuruit
  and mario upon registration in unitycontainer.
- I create a factory that will create the game base on type and inject
  unitycontainer to it. *"I think factory is way to go"*
- I added ITable implemented in Table and registered it also and resolved that Table using ITable so that it will give you flexibility if you later decided to decorate it with different implementation
- I create a service that will do the business logic.

Example Code :

```
// Put this registration in composite root
var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, TictacToe>("tictactoe");
unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, TrivialPursuit>("triviapursuit");
unityContainer.RegisterType<IGame, Mario>("mario");
unityContainer.RegisterType<IGameFactory, GameFactory>(unityContainer);
unityContainer.RegisterType<IGameService, GameService>();
unityContainer.RegisterType<ITable, Table>();

// Game factory implementation
public class GameFactory : IGameFactory
{
     private readonly IUnityContainer _unityContainer;

     public GameFactory(IUnityContainer unityContainer)
     {
         if( unityContainer == null )
             throw new NullReferenceException("unityContainer");

         _unityContainer = unityContainer;
     }

     // GameType should be equal to the name upon registratoin 
     // Ex. Game registered is tictactoe
     //     GameType should be also tictactoe upon resolving.
     public ITable CreateGame(string gameType)
     {
         var gameSelected = _unityContainer.Resolve<IGame>(gameType)

         return _unityContainer.Resolve<ITable>(new ResolverOverride[]
         {
             new ParameterOverride("IGame", gameSelected)
         });
     }
}

// Game service implementation
public class GameService : IGameService
{
     private readonly IGameFactory _gameFactory;

     public GameService(IGameFactory gameFactory)
     {
         if( gameFactory == null )
             throw new NullReferenceException("gameFactory");

         _gameFactory = gameFactory;
     }

     // To avoid exception for unkown gametype enforce with constant 
     // variable or enum depend on your choice
     public void StartGame(string gameType)
     {
         var tableGame = _gameFactory.CreateGame(gameType);

         tableGame.Play();
         tableGame.GameStatus();    
     }
}
```

**Note :** This code was not tested and I don't have translation of it to VB.net.